# Secondary ID auto increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model that has a requirement to have a secondary id.  I can think of several ways to achieve it, but what would be the best way?  Is it possible to specify auto increment in the migration, or should this be done in a filter?

What would be the best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: How does the secondary auto-incrementing column differ from the normal `id`? Can you derive its value?

Comment: The secondary ID is intended as a "consistent id" for the case if database needs to be migrated and the ActiveRecord id's change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution

```
before_validation :add_secondary_id, :on => :create

def add_secondary_id
  self.secondary_id = self.class.select(:secondary_id).order('secondary_id DESC').first.secondary_id.to_i + 1
end
```

Comment: You have just added a race condition.

Comment: The only other options I can think of that would combat a race condition like this would be to use uuids, add a second auto increment field in your database table, or make the field unique in the database which would at least prevent 2 records from having the same value.